# Refreshing File system using java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload, refresh

After uploading the image over a JSP using Eclipse, I can not get the changes in webContent Folder. For there changes I have to refresh the webContent. How do I refresh the file system or how to display image after uploading?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you do. Do you upload files *via your web application* into your *web application source directory*? Could you please explain in a little bit more detail?

Comment: I upload the file using servlet. then redirect the page to jsp to display this uploaded image but i can not get this image. When i refresh the webContent folder of the eclipse. then i get the changes.so what can i do?

Comment: the approach is fault, unfortunately. The web application is **not** supposed to be modified while it's running (that's a feature that should *only* be used for development). What you would need to do is to store the image *somewhere* (outside of the webapplication, a folder or a DB, for example) and provide a servlet that delivers its content based on some id (filename?).

Comment: ok.thanks.But if i store image outside the webapplication. then how to display image in jsp page.I can get image which is outside the webContent folder in jsp file. Is there any way to display image in jsp page.?

Comment: well, you can map your image-delivering servlet to `/myimage` and just use `/myimage?id=23` to refer to the image with id 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

> A watch service that watches registered objects for changes and
>   events. For example a file manager may use a watch service to monitor
>   a directory for changes so that it can update its display of the list
>   of files when files are created or deleted.

As per [this Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).